# getting file size for box files retrieved via box search

Tags: box-api

My code is as follows:

```
    requestObj.addField(BoxFolder.FIELD_SIZE);
    BoxCollection itemCollection = client.getFoldersManager().getFolderItems(file.getId(),
            (BoxFolderRequestObject) requestObj);
    List<BoxTypedObject> objects = itemCollection.getEntries();
    for (BoxTypedObject innerFile : objects) {
        System.out.println("=============" + innerFile.getExtraData(BoxFolder.FIELD_SIZE));
        System.out.println("=============" + innerFile.getValue(BoxFolder.FIELD_SIZE));

    }
```

It returns null in both System.out

I looked at BoxTypedObject which does not have a way to return file size.

I do see getSize() in BoxItem but that is not returned by `Box.getFolderItems ---> BoxCollection ----> BoxTypedObject`

Please provide a way to get Box file size

More Context:

https://github.com/box/box-java-sdk-v2/issues/58

Answer (score 1):

BoxTypedObject can be various types.
You could do this:
if (innerFile instanceof BoxItem) {
    size = ((BoxItem) innerFile).getSize();
}